# How to unfreeze desktop icons

Tags: xubuntu, xfce

I'm using xubuntu 18.04 which use Xfce. For some reason after a while of using the system, I can't click desktop icons (left/right/double clicks). Still system is working and I'm able to use menu, panels, switch windows, open new programs but not the icons on the desktop.

How to fix this issue?

Comment: running `xfwm4 --replace` makes icons disappear!

Comment: the only way is to force kill (-9) `xfdesktop` and start it again